# SSIS convert excel to text file and import

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I have a recurring issue with importing Excel spreadsheets into SQL Server.  As a work around, I am trying to convert the worksheet to a text file, comma delimited.  I can convert the excel file to text but cannot seem to then import the text file into SQL.  When I try to create a path between the text file and the OLE DB destination.  I do notice that the flat file is showing as a destination ("Flat File Destination").  Is there a way to get this to go from the destination text file to SQL after doing the transformation to text?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You say you're trying to use OLEDB Destination, but the flat file is showing as Destination?   I can't picture what you could be doing to cause this.   Are you maybe using a flat file destination when you should be using a flat file SOURCE?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this in one dataflow, turning your 1st destination into a source, you can't do it like that.

If you have a dataflow that moves the data from an Excel Source to a Flat File Destination, you then need to create a second dataflow that uses the Flat File as a SOURCE, and moves the data to an OLEDB Destination.

Just place the second dataflow after the first one on the Control Flow.

Comment: Thanks Tab.  Yes I discovered that.  I am now getting an error that it cannot convert one of the fields because of a potential loss of data.  This is an integer field.  When I convert it in the first flow, the result is a 4 bit signed integer (don't know if that is the best value) and I use the same in the second flow.  I have tried decimal, float, but I may just make it text and see if that works.  The debug says DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMATIONFAILUREONERROR.